# Piping commands in $()

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, grep

This is an example of a shell script I'm trying to run, but instead of printing out the grep'ed result, it prints the whole string. Is it not possible to pipe when in `$()`?

```
i="the cat is a crazy"; word=$( echo $i | grep cat); echo $word;
```

Comment: To answer the question in a strict sense: yes it is possible to pipe with `$()`, as it is a fully functional subshell. The thing is, `grep` doesn't exactly do what you expect it to. It prints lines containing the expression, which in this case is the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Have you just run

```
$ echo $i | grep cat
> the cat is a crazy
```

[From the manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

Grep `print lines matching a pattern`

You want to use -

```
-o, --only-matching
Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line.

$ i="the cat is a crazy"; word=$( echo $i | grep -o cat ); echo $word;
> cat
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `grep -o` to get just a single word out of a line. `grep`’s default behavior is to print out the whole line where a match is found.